# How to get MySQL table names from a database and put them in a arraylist

Tags: java, mysql

How would I get all the table names from a database and put them into a arraylist?

Comment: Please post what did you try first

Comment: Dare we ask 'why?'

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods.

```
SHOW TABLES;

SHOW TABLES IN dbname;

SHOW TABLES FROM dbname;

SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname';
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to use information_schema in query.

Execute following query :

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA='dbname'
```

Now, get data from query and put it into array.